# Camera intrinsic matrix convention on image-space origin

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration

Let's call pixel (0,0) the top left pixel in a camera frame/image.

In OpenCV (for example when using an intrinsic camera matrix produced by OpenCV's camera calibration module), image-space location (0,0) refers to which of the following?

1. The center of top left pixel
2. The top left corner of the top left pixel (making (0.5,0.5) the center of the top left pixel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(0,0) is the center of that pixel.

I can't point to specific documentation but it's implied all throughout the library, mostly by how sampling/resizing works.

when in doubt about a specific API, test its behavior. such things are unfortunately not specified or documented well.

Comment: However, cx and cy in the intrinsic matrix from the calibration module appear to be defined as w/2 and h/2 respectively. This would be inconsistent with this answer.

Comment: Actually I was using an outdated version of OpenCV for calibration. This has been changed so your answer is correct: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/commit/9a4404276a809263e65a8e1f2066722ebd62fdfa

Comment: yes, that code is the kind of "close enough" I see more often than I'd like